# Find Text Between words in Java

Tags: java, regex, search

I want to get all text in between 2 words(1st word is fixed[One] but 2nd is either of 2 words[Two]Or[Three] ).

**Note** :: There may be or may not be space between found text and 2nd word. 
For example:

```
One     i am  
here
Two
i am fine 
One     i am 
here 
 Two
i am fine 
One     i am  
here
Three
i am fine 
One     i am  
here 
 Two
i am fine
```

What i found is

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\bOne\\b)(.*?)(?=\\bTwo\\b)");
```

But this is not correct as It takes complete word.

"Two" is valid.
"fineTwo" is not valid.

Comment: Your lookbehind seems invalid. Try: `(?<=One)(.*?)(?=\\b(?:Two|Three)\\b)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It matches only on complete words, because you use word boundaries `\b`. If you want to accept "fineTwo", then remove the first boundary

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\bOne\\b)(.*?)(?=Two\\b)");
```

To accept either "Two" or "Three" as end, use an alternation:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\bOne\\b)(.*?)(?=(?:Two|Three)\\b)");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for(String parseOne : Input.split("One"))
  for (String parseTwo : parseOne.split("Two"))
    for (String parseThree : parseTwo.split("Three"))
       System.out.println(parseThree.replace("One", "").replace("Two", "").replace("Three", "").trim());
```

Answer (score 0):

getTextBetweenTwoWords method may work.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String firstWord = "One";
    String secondword = "Two";
    String text = "One Naber LanTwo";
    System.out.println(getTextBetweenTwoWords(firstWord, secondword, text));
}
private static String getTextBetweenTwoWords(String firstWord, String secondword, String text)
{
    return text.substring(text.indexOf(firstWord) + firstWord.length(), text.indexOf(secondword));
}
```